# In React-Redux, How to click only the parent component, but not the child one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-redux, dom-events

I'm gonna dispatch an action by clicking.

---

```
export default function Example() {

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  
  function dispatching() {
    dispatch(action)
  }

  return (
    <Parent onClick={dispatching}>
      <Child />
    </Parent>
  )

}
```

---

I want nothing happens when I click the child one.
But it's hard to solve it because of the bubbling, I guess.
I don't think it is related to e.stopPropagation(), because that is useful when I want to click the child one, not the parent one. This is the opposite situation. I already have tried it for if I'm confused, and it didn't work as expected. Please help me, thank you.

Comment: You want to capture the event - which means it goes parent -> child rather than bubble the event, which means it goes from child -> parent (default behaviour). When you capture the event, do the same stopPropagation and it won't make it to the child.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the spacing you have in your onClick.

```
export default function Example() {

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  
  function dispatching() {
    dispatch(action)
  }

  return (
    <Parent onClick={dispatching}>
      <Child />
    </Parent>
  )

}
```

Comment: While indeed cleaner it actually works if you have spaces and is also not answer to the question.